# Is Natsu Dragneel "END" in the Fairy Tail anime adaptation?

Tags: fairy-tail

So I've heard/read that Natsu is END (Etherious Natsu Dragneel), but in the anime END doesn't get activated. In the manga we see that Zeref's reveals who he/it is, but not in the anime.

Is Zeref going to come back and awaken END (Because I'm sticking with the anime, not the manga)? Or is Natsu END even in the anime? (It could just be Hiiro not sticking with the manga?)

Comment: The anime has yet to reach that particular part of the manga. When it does, Natsu's background will probably be revealed.

Comment: @Omry really ? Oh ,, I didn't realize it ,, but thank you☺️✨

Comment: @Omry the anime has revealed that point, though it may have been in an after credits scene, but it was before the 1 year timeskip, which the anime went on hiatus an episode or two after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zeref has confirmed Natsu is E.N.D Etherios Natsu Dragneel. Zeref also confirmed that Natsu is his brother.

The "activate" metaphor the manga uses is to hint that Natsu is not truly aware of his identity. Natsu lives in an ignorant bliss - the cause of this is unknown. E.N.D would therefore be activated when Natsu knows who he truly is and acts in that capacity.

Answer (score 3):

As was pointed out in the comments, they jumped ahead a bit on the reveal of Natsu's identity. Towards the end of the episode where Fairy Tail was disbanded, while Natsu is wandering off to go training...we cut over to Zeref telling Natsu to surpass him, and addresses him by his full name: Etherius Natsu Dragneel.

Per the Manga, We discover that Natsu is (probably) E.N.D. in Chapter 416, but it is fully and completely confirmed a few chapters later.

The anime went on hiatus as of Episode 277, which is adapted from Chapters 417 and 419...so if they followed the manga strictly, we wouldn't know yet. But, obviously, they wanted to pull that reveal before the series went on hiatus again.

So yes. Natsu is E.N.D.

Comment: The anime already had Zeref say Natsu was END. It was right before the 1 year timeskip, right after makarov disbands fairy tail i believe. The anime went on hiatus one episode (maybe 2) after the 1 year timeskip.

Comment: @Ryan I guess I have to rewatch that part ,, but thank you☺️

Comment: I went and looked, Chapter 416, Page 36 is where Zeref Officially reveals Natsu is indeed END.